# Finding the derivative of the equation.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know the answer, but I don't know how to get to it. If someone could explain it to me would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

$y=(\arctan(x))^3$

Answer (score 0):

if $$y=(\arctan x)^3$$

Then by using [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

you would get your answer

**Chain Rule**

$$y=g(f(x))$$

Then $$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$$
$$y'=\frac{3(\arctan x )^2}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: This is my first time in calculus and I don't really understand it. Would you mind explaining it in layman's terms? Thank you.

Comment: @user187751 What exactly you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already proven$^1$ that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Now, using the chain rule, we find that

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\arctan x)^3=3(\arctan x)^2\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\arctan x=\frac{3(\arctan x)^2}{1+x^2}$$

---

$^1$ If not, then [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Arctangent_Function) is a reference.